# Kafka streams count messages in topic and only send these messages to new topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

We have topic "A". On receiving messages we try to decode the payload in these messages. When an exception is thrown whilst decoding the payload, we send this message to another topic. "A-errors". The developer fixes the error and now makes a call to an endpoint to tell kafka to push the messages from "A-errors" back to topic "A" where the decoder will try to decode the payload again (hopefully without throwing an exception).

We're currently using kafka streams to send the messages from topic "A-errors" to topic "A". This will cause an infinite loop if the fix done by the developer did not fix the decoding issue. Is there a way to count the messages in the "A-errors" topic and make it possible to transfer only x amount of messages to "A" and after that close the stream?

We want to cut all of the messages that are already present in topic "A-errors" and paste them in topic "A". When the decoding fails, the message has to be sent back to "A-errors" but it may not be decoded again until we make another endpoint call.

This is the function that gets called on the endpoint:

```
    public void initializeKafkaStreams() {
        String inputTopic = "A-errors";
        String outputTopic = "A";
        Properties streamsConfiguration = new Properties();

        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "test");
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");

        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());

        try {
            Path stateDirectory = Files.createTempDirectory("kafka-streams");
            streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, stateDirectory.toAbsolutePath().toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Building a Streaming Topology
        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<String, String> rawMessages = builder.stream(inputTopic);
        
        rawMessages.foreach((devId, obj) -> System.out.println(obj));

        //Handling Results
        rawMessages.to(outputTopic, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

        //Starting KafkaStream Job
        Topology topology = builder.build();
        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, streamsConfiguration);
        streams.start();

        //Close stream when all NEW messages from "A-errors" already got transferred to "A"
        //streams.close();
    }
```

Comment: There is no way to "count" messages without consuming them. It'd be better if you made `inputTopic` a `Pattern` variable, then expose that as an env-var rather than needing to recompile the app to change the input topic(s). Then if you want to consume the errors topic, you simply need to restart the code with new env-vars

Comment: When would I know when the queue gets finished? When the queue gets finished I want to switch back to my normal input topic.

Comment: You'd need to monitor the consumer group lag for that topic

Comment: I fixed my issue by doing the following: I created an endpoint which gets called when I want to reprocess messages that failed. This endpoint will start the stream. When a message fails it will get flagged (hasFailed = true). If a message has already failed I know I'm processing old messages and I stop the stream. I just monitor if the lag on topic A-errors goes down or not. Thank you for the reply.